# NodeJS async.parallel success gets called twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

See my code

```
router.get('/:productSlug', function(req, res, next) {
    async.parallel({
        product: function(callback) {
            products.single(callback, req,res,next)
        }
    },
    function(err, results){
        console.log('HERE');
        console.log(results.product.rows[0]);
        res.render('product', {product : results.product.rows[0]});
    });
});
```

My console outputs as following

```
HERE
{ name: 'Test Product',
  price: '19.99' }
GET /img/logo.png 304 9.127 ms - -
GET /img/social/share.png 304 2.051 ms - -
GET /img/social/tweet.png 304 2.190 ms - -
HERE
undefined
```

So it works but seems to be calling it again and the second call is meaning undefined parts making the whole things break.

Any ideas - i am totally lost!

Edit: Added the function that is called...

```
single: function (callback, req, res, next){
    var client = new req.app.locals.pg.Client(req.app.locals.pgCon);
    client.connect(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return callback(['could not connect to postgres', err], null);
        }
        client.query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE slug=$1', [req.params.productSlug], function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                return callback(['error running query', err], null);
            }
            return callback(null, result)
            client.end();
        });
    });
}, //End function : single
```

Comment: I just did some test with `async.parallel` and didn't got any issues. What does `products.single` ? Are you sure it calls `callback` only once ? `async` doc mentions that calling the callback more that once may result in unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: I've edited that to add it in. I'm pretty sure it doesn't :/

Comment: This really looks like calling `callback` multiple times. Can you add a `console.log()` statement before each call (or debug using breakpoints etc)?

Comment: Where do those `GET` lines in the log come from? What else is running?

Comment: It just debug on NODEMON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are opening the page in browser, it sends additional request to `/favacon.ico` - be sure to handle it.

Comment: Strangely there is a request for `GET /products/favicon.ico 200 581.813 ms - 479` but it's after the undefined call?

Comment: Turn out this was what it was!, the long ms lag was a give away!